# Using ' = ' as part of latex enumerate counter

Tags: escaping, latex

I'm trying to define an enumerate environment in which I list several iterations of the form

```
i=0: //stuff in 0th iteration

i=1: //some more stuff. And so on…
```

I've tried

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=i=~\arabic*:]
\setcounter{enumii}{-1}
\item some stuff
\end{enumerate}
```

However, that results in

```
i some stuff
```

And escaping the = like so

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=i\=~\arabic*:]
\setcounter{enumii}{-1}
\item some stuff
\end{enumerate}
```

Gives something somewhat like a superscripted hyphen (it's in the source, though stackexchange doesn't seem to display it):

```
i0: some stuff
```

Comment: I think this post will help https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37740/enumerate-with-properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use `=` as part of the property setting with [`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) (and most other key-value setups), you need to hide `=` by using a group; as in `<key>={<valA>=<valB>}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label={$i = \arabic*$:},start=0]
  \item some stuff
  \item some more stuff
  \item \ldots
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```